# Non-versioned SVN directory?

Tags: svn, version-control

The issue we have is a customer supplies us with content to include in releases, and this includes a lot of video files. Their content generally goes in SVN but since they don't have access to it, versioning these large binary files doesn't really seem to fit SVN well. Our testing doesn't require these files (we just have to test we can launch a video if it's found) and we aren't responsible for checking/testing the customer's supplied content.

So I wondered if it's possible to have a SVN dir which isn't versioned, and is just a regular directory which can still be pulled when updating/checking-out?
Or maybe SVN has a way to pull files from a non-SVN source, somewhat like svn:externals but not looking at another repo?

Is there a SVN solution to this, or if we want to avoid versioning the files should we simply put them in another store and configure a build/deploy script to pull them separately?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your question... wouldn't this be solved by setting `svn:ignore *` on such a directory and not committing anything in there ?

Comment: Please note that "still be pulled when updating/checking-out" part.

Comment: If however you do want to version-control large files, SVN imposes no special limits or something. For better separation, you may want to consider using dedicated branches as an alternative to `svn:external` for trees containing these large objects and merging the no-large-files tree against them as needed.

Comment: @John - if you just need to maintain the directory structure, check in the video directories as soft link, and no choice to deploy script to pull the videos separately

Comment: @John - but if you able to find a workaround, is definitely a +1

Comment: Symbolic links do not work in Windows versions older than Vista.  (I do not even know if SVN was updated to support Window's symbolic links at all).

Comment: @gimpg - did anyone mentioned windows ?

Comment: @ajreal well since Windows has like 90% share of PCs, it's sensible to assume Windows rather than assume not Windows. For reference, it _is_ Windows but any OS-specific SVN trick is not very elegant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem the bridge between your client and the SVN repo, or the versioning of binary files ?

For the second one, I think there's no big deal. Read from here : http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/faq/svnbinary.html

> Note that whether or not a file is
>   binary does not affect the amount of
>   repository space used to store changes
>   to that file, nor does it affect the
>   amount of traffic between client and
>   server. For storage and transmission
>   purposes, Subversion uses a diffing
>   method that works equally well on
>   binary and text files; this is
>   completely unrelated to the diffing
>   method used by the svn diff command.

Since versioning of big files can be rude for developers when updating/committing small changes, you can use a dedicated series of branches.

Comment: @JB Jansen - is video NOT the tiny images

Comment: Although I think this answer is not perfect in form, it is still correct.  Why was it downvoted?

Comment: So what ? Too much disk space used ? It is insignificant compared to the value of good project management. Please notice I'm not alone to recommend versioning of theses files.

Comment: @JB Jansen - i have svn check in and check out about 1M of static files (+-100Gb) before, it just way too slow ... and almost killed the server

Comment: @ajreal: Sorry, I fail to parse what you mean.  1 MegaByte of binary files leads to unacceptably slow performance?  My experience tells me that this is incorrect.

Comment: @ajreal: However, if you mean 1 Million files, within a deep folder structure, than this is a problem with the SVN workinng copy format on Windows.  It does not matter than if it is 1kB text-files, or 100 MB binary-files (though your server should have some decent amount of RAM available).

Comment: @gimpf - 1 million of static files, ps: not on windows

Comment: @JD... the issue is not wanting the files to be versioned. We don't want our customer accessing our SVN... apart from anything else they will screw it up!

Answer (score 4):

Alas no, subversion stores all versions committed to it - there's no flag to set to tell it to keep just the last version. Maybe one day after obliterate is implemented, but don't hold your breath waiting for that :)

Basically, there isn't a SVN solution to this - so you need to look at a document-management server, or just a separate file store.

There is one option that might work for you though, if you use TortoiseSvn, you can use its [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) to automatically pull the video files from the file store to the local system.

The alternative for an all-subversion solution is to store your video files in it as normal, but then regularly dump/filter/load the repository to clean out the old versions. this can take some time if the video files are very large so I'm not sure if I recommend it, but if you stored them in their own repo, you could simply get the latest version, delete the entire repo, and re-import the file you just got to re-initialise the repo with 1 version. Saves space, and could be scripted, but probably isn't worth the hassle comapred to just telling everyone "get your video files off "\server\videos".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right but as far as I've understood it you are after isolation between your code and your customer's huge binary files.

What about this, 
Set up a separate dedicated SVN repository for your large files. 
Grant the customer access only to that repository.
Use the svn:externals to pull these files into your code tree.

SVN do handle large binary files pretty well and if you put them in a separate repo they won't pollute your code repo.

Comment: Users can't be trusted with SVN.